# 500 internal server error occured in CakePHP 3?

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp-3.0

My first .htaccess file in root folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/ [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

My second .htaccess file in webroot folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

My third .htaccess file in src folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

After doing this it results in a `500 internal server error` in CakePHP 3.

Comment: I notice that a number of your questions include "please help" and sometimes "urgent" - it's worth bearing in mind that these will generally get edited out, and that some readers so dislike requests for urgency that they will downvote the question. Do remember that all readers are volunteers here, and all questions are of equal importance.

Comment: What evidence makes you think it's a .htaccess problem? From what you've presented, it could just as well be a coding or configuration error in your application.

Comment: i found solution in cakephp 2.0 we need three htaccess file but in cakephp 3.0 we need only 2 cakephp file (root directory, webroot folder)..

In root directory --

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>

in webroot folder --

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

Answer (score 2):

I would first try double checking your init process verse the cakePHP3 docs http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html -- not knowing more of your local setup, this is where I would start

Answer (score 0):

Change every

```
RewriteEngine on
```

By this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
```